# PhoneGap 1.9 Barcode Scanner iOS issue

Tags: cordova, barcode

All,

Has anyone a working example of the Barcode scanner for iOS that works?  I have downloaded the plugins and deployed the example it to my iphone 4 with 5.01ver of OS.  it loads i hit the "Scan Something" button and nothing happens, no errors just nothing.  I know this version is with 1.5 of Cordova.  However i followed the example and instructions in the plugin in a 1.9 version and it is doing the same thing.  I have double checked the plist and it all matches the example's plist and the instructions. I did put a console.log in the barcodescanner.js file in the "scan" function and it never gets there or at least it never displays it in the output window.  any ideas?  I see someone else posted the exact same question for 1.8.1 but no one answered him...

thanks

tim

Answer (score 0):

I just installed on a vanilla 1.9.0 with the directions exactly as they appear at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner and it opens the scanner for me.

At the moment I can't get it to recognise that it has scanned a barcode though.

Is there something in your document/device ready function that is crashing before it registers the on click event for the scan button? Like hitting a url that isn't in your whitelist or something like that.

Further to that can you edit your code that calls the scan function?